# Database independence through JDBC in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

There are some limitations of using JDBC and database dependency is one of those limitations.

Is there any pattern or way to achieve database independence in JDBC (without using any other ORM framework or tool).

I have tried to achieve this through dynamic polymorphism (created specific classes for different DBMS and overridden common CRUD operations according to specific SQL syntax).

For example, is there a way to write generic SQL statements so that they can be executed in almost every SQL related DBMS?

Comment: ORMs do exactly that (beside many other convenient features). Have you tried [JPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API)?

Comment: id say `CriteriaQuery` would be very generic, but it  requires JPA which is an ORM

Comment: I think that you shouldn't go with your classes which override CRUD operations for specific SQL syntax. There are established tools for that, JPA (interface), Hibernate (an implementation), Spring-data (default CRUD operations easily). Don't reinvent the wheel. What you can try -- in simple cases -- is to use JDBC, BUT use only the subset of SQL which is supported by all of the databases you are deploying for. (ANSI sql-92 can be a starting point).

Comment: hi there !!
I have a limitation to achieve it through JDBC only.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is ANSI SQL ?
I mean I am aware of normal SQL statements and I know how to perform CRUD operations on MySQL (including joins) but what is ANSI SQL ?
Is it some set of rules or standards following to which we can generate generic SQL that will work on any SQL DBMS ??

Comment: SQL is a standard defined by the ANSI committee. It defines features that a DBMS should or has to implement to comply with that standard. **No** DBMS today supports the full SQL standard and every DBMS has additional features that are not part of the SQL standard. MySQL is one example of a DBMS with a very poor compliance with the SQL standard (non-standard string concatentation, non-standard boolean evaluation, only partial support for constraints missing [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) features, ...).

Comment: You might want to look into abstraction layers that are somewhere between pure JDBC and a full blown ORM (=obfuscated relational model). QueryDSL, JOOQ and and sql2o would be such layers.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303082/database-independency-through-jdbc-in-java, are you using two different accounts to circumvent the rules here?

Comment: Mark: the link posted by you in the comment is the link of this question itself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The future of MySQL looks promising. Window functions, recursive CTE in MySQL 8: http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes

Comment: @LukasEder: shrug - I don't really care. MySQL/MariaDB is not relevant to me. I have used all those features for years already in Postgres and the pace at which Postgres moves still leaves MySQL (or MariaDB) the second choice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was just replying to your "modern SQL features" claim...

Comment: Oops, I meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299530/how-to-achieve-database-independence-through-jdbc (BTW: Hint, use @<username> to notify people in comments)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55909481/521799

Answer (score 48):

I think I'm qualified to answer, being the author of [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org), which was already suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303248/521799). As I've shown, it's totally possible to achieve what you're trying to do, but there is a long long road ahead for you, if you want to roll your own.

#### Let's talk about JDBC

JDBC is an excellent network protocol abstraction, so it's a great starting point. There are quite a few caveats though as you move on to solving more complex problems inside of an API like the one you're trying to build. For instance:

- Fetching generated keys is really hard. Few JDBC drivers get this right
- Are you sure you're handling LOBs correctly? Hint: You're not
- What's worse than LOBs? LOBs inside of Oracle OBJECT types
- Have I mentioned Oracle OBJECT types? They can be put inside of arrays (and arrays of arrays. That's when stuff gets really hairy
- But Oracle's OBJECT types are wonderful, compared to PostgreSQL's TYPE types. The JDBC driver doesn't help you *at all*, there
- Try binding DB2 `NULL` values. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
- Want to support `java.sql.Date` *and* `java.time.LocalDate`? Good luck!
- Speaking of dates, do you know how many different kinds of interpretations of the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type there are?
- Want to support `INTERVAL` types? Really?
- What if the database throws more than one exception?
- What if the database raises errors through a different API than exceptions (hello SQL Server)
- What if you need to collect warnings prior to fetching exceptions?
- Did you know that some databases first send you an update count, and *only then* the actual result set (e.g. when triggers fire)
- Have you thought of handling multiple result sets?
- Now combine the above with formal `OUT` parameters
- Let's talk about the `BOOLEAN` type
- ... I could go on for hours. [More examples on this website](https://www.jooq.org/hacking-jdbc)
- Did you know that some PostgreSQL statements don't work when `autoCommit` is set to true?
- Not everyone supports savepoints
- Want to use JDBC `DatabaseMetaData` to reverse engineer your schema? Forget it!
- Want to use `ResultSetMetaData` to discover qualified column names? Well...

As you've seen, even if JDBC does its job really well for most people (and there's always a hacky workaround for each of the above that *works for an individual database*. But you want to write an API that works on all databases, so you have to fix / work around all of the above. Trust me. That'll keep you busy for a while!

#### Let's talk about SQL

But thus far, we've only discussed how hard it is to bind to JDBC. We haven't discussed how hard it is to standardise SQL. So let's discuss that for a moment:

- `LIMIT n OFFSET m` is nice, eh? Or is it `LIMIT m, n`? Or `TOP n START AT m`? Or `OFFSET m ROWS FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY`? What if you want to support older databases? Will you roll your own `ROW_NUMBER()` filtering? [Here, I've documented it for you](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/).
- Some databases support `SELECT` without `FROM`. In other databases, you need something like a `DUAL` table. [There you go, all documented](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/dual/).
- Some databases pretend they don't need that `DUAL` table, until their parser breaks and you still need it (hello MySQL)
- Some databases support `SELECT` without `FROM`, but they do require `FROM` for `WHERE` / `HAVING` / `GROUP BY`
- What's your take on this: `(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) UNION ALL SELECT 3`. Will it work on all databases? (I mean the parenthesised nesting)
- Is `EXCEPT ALL` supported? Is `EXCEPT` even supported?
- Is `FULL OUTER JOIN` supported?
- Do derived tables need an alias or can they live without one?
- Is the keyword `AS` permitted on derived tables?
- Can the `ORDER BY` clause contain expressions referencing aliases from the `SELECT` clause? Or only expressions referencing columns from the `FROM` clause?
- Can the `ORDER BY` clause contain expressions at all?
- Can derived tables contain an `ORDER BY` clause?
- Let's talk about functions. Is it call `SUBSTRING()` or `SUBSTR()` or `INSTR()` or what?
- Hint, [this is how to emulate the `REPEAT()` function on SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568496/521799)
- How would you emulate the `VALUES()` constructor, as in `SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) t(a)`? Few databases have native support
- In fact, how would you emulate the derived column list (aliasing `table(column)` in one go) if it's not supported? [Here's a funky idea](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/01/07/simulating-the-sql-standard/).
- In fact, let's discuss row value expressions and predicates built with them. This: `(a, b) > (x, y)` is the same as this: `a > x OR a = x AND b > y`. The former isn't supported everywhere
- PostgreSQL's `UPDATE .. RETURNING` can be emulated using a PL/SQL block in Oracle 12c:

  ```
  declare
    t0 dbms_sql.number_table;
    t1 dbms_sql.date_table;
    c0 sys_refcursor;
    c1 sys_refcursor;
  begin
    update "TEST"."T_2155"
    set "TEST"."T_2155"."D1" = date '2003-03-03'
    returning 
      "TEST"."T_2155"."ID", 
      "TEST"."T_2155"."D1"
    bulk collect into t0, t1;
    ? := sql%rowcount; // Don't forget to fetch the row count
    open c0 for select * from table(t0);
    open c1 for select * from table(t1);
    ? := c0; // These need to be bound as OracleTypes.CURSOR OUT params
    ? := c1; // These need to be bound as OracleTypes.CURSOR OUT params
  end;
  ```

#### Conclusion

As you can see, it can totally be done. I've done it, it's called [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org). It's probably been the biggest challenge of my professional life and it has been fun. [jOOQ 3.10 will feature a parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/), which can [translate from a SQL string (in any dialect) to another SQL string (in a specific dialect)](https://www.jooq.org/translate/), which is the next level of vendor agnosticity.

But it was a long way to go to get here. Before I did jOOQ (started in 2009), I've worked with Oracle SQL and in-house JDBC-based frameworks (like the one you're planning to write) intensively. I wrote jOOQ because I've seen many in-house frameworks being written and none of them did the job well. The developers always tackled `SELECT` .. `FROM` .. `WHERE` - which is the easy part. Some managed to get `JOIN` in the game, and perhaps `GROUP BY` and that's it. They then abandoned the task, because they had more important stuff to do than maintain boring and buggy infrastructure software.

Now, I don't know what your motivation is to do this yourself, but my advice here is:

- Use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) if you want to write vendor-agnostic SQL
- Use [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org) if you want to implement vendor-agnostic object-graph persistence

You can try building your own jOOQ (or Hibernate). It's a fun challenge. But if you have deadlines, I really suggest you review the above options.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, database independence is hard. Really, really hard; to achieve it without using an ORM or other tool, you will have to trade some other aspect of your solution design. Simplicity and maintainability will suffer, as will the effort to implement the solution.

So, I'd make really, really sure that this is a high priority requirement - a hypothetical "what if we want to switch from Oracle to SQL Server" question is - in my opinion - not sufficient justification to incur the additional costs...

If you *must* deliver this feature, and ORM is by far the easiest way to do it. The ORM frameworks are specifically designed with database independence in mind (and their complexity is at least in part due to that requirement). They do so by abstracting away the database implementation into a higher level; instead of thinking in SQL statements, you're encouraged to think about domain objects.

Having said all that...

I have delivered a solution (not in Java, but the principle stands) which allowed database independence. We stored our SQL statements as resources, and loaded them via resource files. The default was ANSI SQL, which *should* work on any modern SQL-compatible database.

We had resource files for each database flavour we supported (in our case MySQL and Oracle), and used overrides to load in database-specific SQL statement if they existed.

This works like internationalization in most languages - look for locale-specific strings first, fall back to default if you can't find one.

Java's resource bundle would make this pretty easy. Not hardcoding your SQL in your application has other benefits - fixing a database problem without changing the application code is much easier, you can deploy fixes as "resource" updates rather than shipping a new binary etc.

Comment: +1 - With plain jdbc, this is the way I would recommend and people should have expertise in various RDBMs and that is hardly true for any team.

Comment: "Simplicity and maintainability will suffer" [citation needed]. Personally I find both jOOQ and QueryDSL a boon for maintainability, as they enable the compiler to type check queries, and the IDE to support refactorings.

Comment: Hi @meriton - I agree that JOOQ and QueryDSL are great - and they do enhance maintainability. However, the question said "without using ORM or any other tool". If you roll your own, I think it's reasonable to say you're sacrificing simplicity and maintainability...

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to address database portability:

1. Subtracting non-common features - You can remove all database-specific features, which will leave you with a SQL-92 feature set. This is what ORM tools do because the common CRUD statements are handled almost identically by all RDBMS. However, when you need to execute database-specific queries, you turn to native SQL.
2. Specialization - You can use database-specific dialects and emulate functionality from one DB to another, like PIVOT. This is the approach used by [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).

However, since you explicitly stated that:

> Is there any pattern or way to achieve database independence in JDBC
> (without using any other ORM framework or tool).

You need to solve this problem using JDBC API, right?

The only way to do it, without taking neither the ORM or jOOQ approach which practically means implementing your own data access framework, is to use a custom DAO for each supported database.

So, you can define the DAO interfaces that are used by the Service layer, like `ProductDAO` and implement each and one for every supported database:

- `OracleProductDAOImpl`
- `MySQLProductDAOImpl`
- `PostgreSQLProductDAOImpl`
- `SQLServerProductDAOImpl`

Or, you can use a single `ProductDAOImpl`, but then you need to use stored procedures and make sure each stored procedure is implemented in the database.

So, although it's possible, you are basically where we were in the early 2000s when we didn't have either Hibernate or jOOQ. From my experience, it's way more work than if you used a mature data access framework.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that what you're actually trying to build there by creating a library that allows you to generically access a database is quite similar to what many of the ORMs already do.

Have you tried jOOQ? it's quite different to the other ORMs out there and does what you're looking for. One could refer to it as a "tool" but then I could also refer to what you're trying to build as a "tool".

jOOQ strives to be a java native language for making portable DB calls so sounds like it's exactly what you're looking for.

https://www.jooq.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
But i need to do it through JDBC only. As of now i am not allowed to use any ORM tool or frameworks.
I am looking for a way to achieve this through JDBC only.

Comment: Ok but keep in mind that what you've said here is pretty much exactly the starting point that the guys who built jOOQ started at. So at the end of the day you will be using a tool or framework, it'll just be one you've built instead of a pre-existing one.

Comment: Nothing says fantastic idea better than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

While (very) late to the party and not bringing anything new really, I'd like to endorse a bit and expand on [Neville's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303810/272939) and [Vlad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44326424/272939) answers (as a plausible option).

Frameworks like jOOQ and Hibernate are, probably, the better way to go, especially ***IF*** what you're trying to obtain is something completely generic (i.e. handle most imaginable DB operations) as opposed to *a handful of specific tasks involving SQL*. However, since it seems they're not an option for you, *externalizing SQL* in one way or another could actually take you quite far (from an SQL dialect point of view, not necessarily from the JDBC binding issues so nicely outlined in [Lukas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323668/272939) before).

I've previously worked on a custom Java-based ETL engine (successfully) running on both Oracle and DB2. As you can imagine, we needed the best queries we could get in terms of speed and our DBAs were optimizing them using every trick in the book and then some! So, not only had we 2 SQL dialects to accommodate, but the queries we had to execute were also highly customized (hints etc.)... The solution we settled upon was to *generate the SQLs at runtime, using a template engine* (Velocity, at the time) and *custom templates*, tailored for the target DB (probably similar to the way Hibernate or jOOQ build they final SQL). Admittedly, we had our own "context" with specific and well defined needs…